# how to achieve Upload functionality in a Spring roo proj using a reverse engineering approch?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I  am  trying  to  implement  a file upload functionality in a spring roo proj  using  reverse engineering method were i have my  data base and table has a blob object  now  when i  generate  a the roo proj  it could  not  achieve the  upload  functionality 
 the Blob field is displayed as  text field  but not  with file  browse option .
please  can any  one help  me out  in achieving this.

Comment: Lay off the hashish, buddy.

Comment: did not get you Jason wht should  i  do .?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying: Spring Roo is not a genie in a bottle, magician, and it's definitely not a magic bullet.  What I mean by this is:  You can do a LOT of cool things quickly with Roo, but in the end, you will almost ALWAYS have to code something somewhere.

Ok, so you need to do a file upload.  You created your table, reverse-engineered your Domain objects, and then scaffolded the Controller and all the JSP code.  The problem is: Spring Roo doesn't know how to handle blobs.  It doesn't know if you intended to store an Image in there, PDF, or that it should be some sort of file upload.  This is where the "custom coding" starts.

What you will need to do is take the JSP Roo spat out and modify it to suite your needs.  Again, **Spring Roo is a shortcut to a means, not a fully baked solution**.

Start by modifying the `<form:form>` tag.  You need to set the encryption type to `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"`.  Next, you will need to include a [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) in your Controller's handler method as an `@RequestParameter`.

There are plenty of "How-Tos" on the inter-webs for this, like [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/), which is a little old but should be pretty relevant.